# From CSV (Double quote enclosed) file how to remove data double quotes with unix

Tags: csv, unix

From CSV (Double quote enclosed) file how to REPLACE data double quotes (means double quote inside data) from 3rd html string field (it has data commas also i.e commas inside data) with ~ symbol with unix.
We should not remove any other double quotes.

Input File:

```
F1,F2,F3
"11111","ABABDBDA","<div style="text-aaa: justify;"> Il MMM delinea l&rsquo;evvv dei ccccc e dei ruorrrrli, degli organi sss, alaaaala "
"22222","PPPPPPPP","<p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style="color:#ff0000;"><strong>Disponibile dal 25/03</strong></span></p> <div style="text-align: justify;"> Il manuale delinea l&rsquo;evoluzione dei , ;"> </div>"
"333333","QQQQQQQ","<p style="text-align: justify;"> Il libro analizza i singoli cicli gestionali, partendo dalle rilevazioni, contabili per giungere poi alla destinazione di "
```

Expected output file:

```
F1,F2,F3
"11111","ABABDBDA","<div style=~text-aaa: justify;> Il MMM delinea l&rsquo;evvv dei ccccc e dei ruorrrrli, degli organi sss, alaaaala" 
"22222","PPPPPPPP","<p style=~text-align: justify;~> <span style=~color:#ff0000;~><strong>Disponibile dal 25/03</strong></span></p> <div style=~text-align: justify;~> Il manual"
"333333","QQQQQQQ","<p style=~text-align: justify;~> Il libro analizza i singoli cicli gestionali, partendo dalle rilevazioni, contabili per giungere poi alla destinazione"
```

I tried with awk command but its not giving expected output

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the `awk` command you tried and the output you got.

Comment: It's not a CSV. Because if you have comma and double quotes inside a cell, a single cell has this kind of structure `"Hello, ""world"""`.  Do you have only 3 fields, where the first two are like in your example and the third is the one to work on?

Comment: Hi! @aborruso is correct, the CSV has some problems around quoting. I use Go's standard CSV parser a lot, and I think it has an option that can read and correct the malformed parts; answer below. Good luck :)

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75308078/757714 ? If you ask questions and get answers, please give feedback

Comment: thanks for suggestions, but I do not have miller, ruby and all

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller 6](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/), and running

```
mlr --csv --lazy-quotes put '$F3=gsub($F3,"\"","~")' input.csv >output.csv
```

you get

```
F1,F2,F3
11111,ABABDBDA,"<div style=~text-aaa: justify;~> Il MMM delinea l&rsquo;evvv dei ccccc e dei ruorrrrli, degli organi sss, alaaaala "
22222,PPPPPPPP,"<p style=~text-align: justify;~> <span style=~color:#ff0000;~><strong>Disponibile dal 25/03</strong></span></p> <div style=~text-align: justify;~> Il manuale delinea l&rsquo;evoluzione dei , ;~> </div>"
333333,QQQQQQQ,"<p style=~text-align: justify;~> Il libro analizza i singoli cicli gestionali, partendo dalle rilevazioni, contabili per giungere poi alla destinazione di "
```

Some notes:

- `--lazy-quotes`, accepts quotes appearing in unquoted fields, and non-doubled quotes appearing in quoted fields
- `put '$F3=gsub($F3,"\"","~")'` to search `"` and replace it with `~`.

Comment: Did you mean to show `'$F3=gsub($F3,"\"","~")'` and _then_ show OP how to completely remove those "interior quotes" in the bulleted point?

Comment: thank you @ZachYoung I hadn't seen it, I'll correct it, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find a solution with awk, here is a very simple Go program that uses the standard library's CSV parser, and its [LazyQuotes option](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv#Reader) (emphasis added for your case):

> If LazyQuotes is true, a quote may appear in an unquoted field and **a non-doubled quote may appear in a quoted field**.

From your original statement and the sample input, it looks to me like the only issue is that quotes for the HTML attributes were not properly escaped when the CSV was created.  I think the LazyQuotes option can handle this correctly, and this seems to me like it would be more desireable than changing the HTML:

```
F1,F2,F3
11111,ABABDBDA,"<div style=""text-aaa: justify;""> Il MMM delinea l&rsquo;evvv dei ccccc e dei ruorrrrli, degli organi sss, alaaaala "
22222,PPPPPPPP,"<p style=""text-align: justify;""> <span style=""color:#ff0000;""><strong>Disponibile dal 25/03</strong></span></p> <div style=""text-align: justify;""> Il manuale delinea l&rsquo;evoluzione dei , ;""> </div>"
333333,QQQQQQQ,"<p style=""text-align: justify;""> Il libro analizza i singoli cicli gestionali, partendo dalle rilevazioni, contabili per giungere poi alla destinazione di "
```

and in table-view:

| F1 | F2 | F3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | ABABDBDA | <div style="text-aaa: justify;"> Il MMM delinea l’evvv dei ccccc e dei ruorrrrli, degli org... |
| 22222 | PPPPPPPP | <p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style="color:#ff0000;"><strong>Disponibile dal 25/03</stro... |
| 333333 | QQQQQQQ | <p style="text-align: justify;"> Il libro analizza i singoli cicli gestionali, partendo dalle ril... |

Here's a smaller sample to try and highlight:

1. creating the CSV reader
2. setting the LazyQuotes option
3. reading all records
4. creating the CSV writer
5. writing all records

No special processing is needed, the CSV parser just does the right thing for you:

```golang
csvBlob := `F1,F2,F3
"11111","ABABDBDA","<div style="text-aaa: justify;"> Il MMM delinea l&rsquo;evvv dei ccccc e dei ruorrrrli, degli organi sss, alaaaala "
"22222","PPPPPPPP","<p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style="color:#ff0000;"><strong>Disponibile dal 25/03</strong></span></p> <div style="text-align: justify;"> Il manuale delinea l&rsquo;evoluzione dei , ;"> </div>"
"333333","QQQQQQQ","<p style="text-align: justify;"> Il libro analizza i singoli cicli gestionali, partendo dalle rilevazioni, contabili per giungere poi alla destinazione di "
`

fIn := strings.NewReader(csvBlob)
r := csv.NewReader(fIn)
r.LazyQuotes = true

records, _ := r.ReadAll()

w := csv.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
w.WriteAll(records)
w.Flush()
```

You can view that in the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/GYl25Ru9UIp) and run it.

Here's a more complete example to read from a file and write to a new file, with error checking:

```golang
fIn, err := os.Open("input.csv")
defer fIn.Close()
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal("could not open input.csv:", err)
}

r := csv.NewReader(fIn)
r.LazyQuotes = true

records, err := r.ReadAll()
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal("could not read CSV:", err)
}

fOut, err := os.Create("output.csv")
defer fOut.Close()
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal("could not create output.csv:", err)
}

w := csv.NewWriter(fOut)
w.WriteAll(records)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ruby:

```
ruby -r csv -e '
puts CSV.parse($<.read, **{:headers=>false, :liberal_parsing=>true}).
    map{|row| row[0..1]+[row[2..].join(",").gsub(/^"|"$/,"").gsub(/"/,"~")]}.
    map{|a| a.to_csv(**{:force_quotes=>true})}.join
' file
```

Prints:

```
"F1","F2","F3"
"11111","ABABDBDA","<div style=~text-aaa: justify;~> Il MMM delinea l&rsquo;evvv dei ccccc e dei ruorrrrli, degli organi sss, alaaaala "
"22222","PPPPPPPP","<p style=~text-align: justify;~> <span style=~color:#ff0000;~><strong>Disponibile dal 25/03</strong></span></p> <div style=~text-align: justify;~> Il manuale delinea l&rsquo;evoluzione dei , ;~> </div>"
"333333","QQQQQQQ","<p style=~text-align: justify;~> Il libro analizza i singoli cicli gestionali, partendo dalle rilevazioni, contabili per giungere poi alla destinazione di "
```